# Regex Modifier error on a perl configure file

Tags: regex, perl, ubuntu-18.04

I was trying to install Genie on my computer (which is running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS), but I am stuck on a piece of code. I am sending you the error message when I try to check the dependencies of the program or the

> ./configure

However, I am getting the following error:

```
    p:~/Downloads/GENIE-Generator_v2.8.6$ ./configure
Bareword found where operator expected at ./configure line 62, near "$/Downloads"
    (Missing operator before Downloads?)
Bareword found where operator expected at ./configure line 71, near "$/Downloads"
    (Missing operator before Downloads?)
Unquoted string "root" may clash with future reserved word at ./configure line 71.
Unquoted string "data" may clash with future reserved word at ./configure line 75.
Unquoted string "banner" may clash with future reserved word at ./configure line 75.
Unquoted string "txt" may clash with future reserved word at ./configure line 75.
Unquoted string "configure" may clash with future reserved word at ./configure line 85.
syntax error at ./configure line 62, near "$/Downloads"
syntax error at ./configure line 71, near "$/Downloads"
Execution of ./configure aborted due to compilation errors.
```

In the configure file, the appropriate lines would be:

```
$GENIE =$/Downloads/GENIE-Generator_v2.8.6;     (ln 62)
$ROOTSYS =$/Downloads/root                      (ln 71)
$BANNER_FILE = $GENIE/data/banner/BANNER.txt;   (ln 75)
```

.

I am a novice in this community, so I'm afraid I don't know a lot about the etiquette and guidelines of this community or of the language. I have a very limited understanding of both the language (Perl) and the OS (Ubuntu), so I'm afraid I would need a step by step solution. I would be very grateful if you could please provide me with one.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is this `configure` file?  By  the looks of the error it is apparently executed as a Perl script, which it isn't (the shown snippet isn't valid Perl).

Answer (score 2):

I found this [GENIE-Generator](http://releases.genie-mc.org/) program and downloaded the (rather old) version 2.8.6. Lines 62, 71 and 75 of the configure script do not match up with what you quoted, nor do I get your errors when trying to run it.

Your copy has been altered in some fashion for some reason from the stock source tarball, and changed into something that isn't valid perl.

What I would do: Delete the whole thing, and re-download a fresh copy of the source (I'd suggest the current release unless you're locked into that old one for some reason), and try again with the new, clean copy.

```
$ rm -rf GENIE-Generator_v2.8.6 GENIE-Generator_v2.8.6.tar.gz
$ wget http://www.hepforge.org/archive/genie/GENIE-Generator_v2.8.6.tar.gz
$ tar xzf GENIE-Generator_v2.8.6.tar.gz
$ cd GENIE-Generator_v2.8.6
$ ./configure
```

(Adjust filenames as needed)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm getting the error:  *** Error *** The GENIE environmental variable (pointing to the top level GENIE directory) is not defined at ./configure line 63.  There seems to be a problem with the configure file, should I try defining the variables as I tried last time?

Comment: I would be very grateful if you could please help me again